# DataTable - Lazy Loading Primefaces showing error

Tags: spring, jsf, datatable, primefaces, lazy-loading

I am using JSF2.0 with PrimeFaces3.1 and Spring3.1 for Business logic.I was trying to use a DataTable- Lazy loading. But It is giving me the following error. Kindly help.

An Error Occurred:

```
/ by zero
- Stack Trace
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
at org.primefaces.model.LazyDataModel.setRowIndex(LazyDataModel.java:62)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndex(UIData.java:448)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.visitColumnsAndRows(UIData.java:1544)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.visitTree(UIData.java:1212)

Please help.
```

Comment: Show us your bean and markup! The exception is misleading. In most cases it is caused by not providing a collection for the `value` attribute of the datatable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its seems like a know issue

[datatable: java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=14023)

[Issue 1544:    LazyDataTable.setRowIndex throws arithmetic exception: division by 0.](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=1544)

---

[It has a FIX/WORKAROUND (so claimed by some user)](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=1544#c21)

Comment: Data Table is not displaying; please help.
<p:panelGrid cellspacing="15" cellpadding="10" style="width:750px;">
 <p:dataTable var="studyPlanList" value="#{editBean.lazyModel}" paginator="true" rows="10"  
     paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"  
     rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" selectionMode="single" selection="" id="studyPlanTable">  
          <p:column headerText="StudyPlan"  >  
            <h:outputText value="#{studyPlanList.name}" />  
        </p:column>  
    </p:dataTable> 
</p:panelGrid

Answer (score 11):

You must override the method **setRowIndex**

Example:

```
@Override
public void setRowIndex( int rowIndex ) {

   if ( rowIndex == -1 || getPageSize() == 0 ) {
    super.setRowIndex( -1 );
   } else
    super.setRowIndex( rowIndex % getPageSize() );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is derivative to [Alfaville](http://This%20answer%20is%20derivative%20to%20Alfaville's%20answer,%20but%20if%20you%20happen%20to%20have%20set%20a%20field%20named%20pageSize%20in%20your%20LazyDataTable%20descendant%20it%20may%20cause%20the%20same%20problem.%20This%20was%20the%20case%20with%20me%20and%20I%20didn't%20see%20the%20problem%20until%20I%20saw%20the%20Override%20of%20setRowIndex.)'s answer, but if you happen to have set a field named `pageSize` in your `LazyDataTable` descendant it may cause the same problem. This was the case with me and I didn't see the problem until I saw the Override of `setRowIndex`.